# Why doesn't javascript mouseleave refresh original image when sliding between 2 images?

Tags: javascript, mouseleave

Digging around and maybe I scanned right past it but I can't find a similar example of how to slide on and off between 2 images in javascript. In other words on hover displaying a 2nd image and them when leaving the hover returning the photo to the original photo.  I have a sample setup here:

Notice I can get a standard mouseover/mouseleave scenario working on the top header but not for the 2 photos below in the codepen example:

Animation of what the problem is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvkbd.gif

Example code:
https://codepen.io/itplainedge/pen/OJEEaME

**See alternative unwanted solution below this code:**

HTML:

```
<h4 id="myH4" >Original Header</h4>

<div id="img1">
<img src="https://comic.browserling.com/bytes.png" alt=""/>
</div>

<div id="img2">
<img src="https://www.thecoderpedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Programming-Memes-Programmer-while-sleeping.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
document.querySelector("#img1").addEventListener('mouseover',leftMouseOver);
document.querySelector("#img1").addEventListener('mouseleave',leftMouseLeave);
document.querySelector("#img2").addEventListener('mouseover',rightMouseOver);
document.querySelector("#img2").addEventListener('mouseleave',rightMouseLeave);


function leftMouseOver(e) {
  console.log("leftMouseOver");
  this.innerHTML='<img src="https://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/themes/codepen/images/codepen-logo-midgray.svg"></img>';  
}
function leftMouseLeave(e) {
  console.log("leftMouseLeave");
  this.innerHTML='<img src="https://comic.browserling.com/bytes.png" alt=""></img>';
}
function rightMouseOver(e) {
  console.log("rightMouseOver");
  this.innerHTML='<img src="https://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/themes/codepen/images/codepen-logo-midgray.svg"></img>';   
}
function rightMouseLeave(e) {
  console.log("rightMouseLeave");
  this.innerHTML='<img src="https://www.thecoderpedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Programming-Memes-Programmer-while-sleeping.jpg" alt=""></img>';
}

document.querySelector("h4").style = "background-color: lightgreen; text-align:center;";
document.querySelector("h4").addEventListener('mouseover',mouseOver);
document.querySelector("h4").addEventListener('mouseleave',mouseUp);
document.querySelector("h4").addEventListener('mousedown',mouseDown);
document.querySelector("h4").addEventListener('mouseup',mouseUp);

function mouseOver(e) {
  this.innerHTML='Mouse Over';
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  this.innerHTML='Mouse Down';
}

function mouseUp(e) {
  this.innerHTML="Original Header";
}
```

**Update:**
The following works using jQuery but I want to leave out the jquery requirement and use vanilla javascript
https://codepen.io/itPPL/pen/LYrBNQY

Comment: `innerHTML` removes all event listeners

Comment: @Konrad, the point of injection is a div parent so innerHTML is the actual img element.

Comment: @Yogi, you must be dragging over the shading to the right of the photo which works fine. The problem seems to show itself when dragging over the actual photos.

Comment: Looked at this closer and your code has multiple problems and design flaws. It would need to be completely rewritten to work correctly. And that's probably why no solutions have been posted and why you didn't find similar examples. One problem is that you are swapping dissimilar images. The svg image is especially problematic as it's made in a way that ignores css. As an alternative, see this [example](https://sirv.com/help/articles/hover-change-image/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Yogi but I was trying to use pure Javascript without having access to the CSS file for this project.

There's always uncleanliness in my code and I tend to do things quite different until I play longer then it gets a little better. My problem is I was trying to change the whole innerHTML/outerHTML when all I needed to do was change the src attribute.

Here is my solution and like usual there might be better and I'll always take suggestions.

https://codepen.io/itPPL/pen/bGKjYbv

HTML:

```
<h4 id="myH4" >Original Header</h4>

<div id="img1">
<img src="https://comic.browserling.com/bytes.png" width="300" height="300"/>
</div>

<div id="img2">
<img src="https://www.thecoderpedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Programming-Memes-Programmer-while-sleeping.jpg" width="300" height="300"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myH4 {font-size:26px;}
#img1{background-color:lightblue;}
#img2{background-color:lightgreen;}
```

Javascript:

```
//Header Functions:
function mouseOver(e) {
  this.innerHTML='Stop that tickles';
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  this.innerHTML='Haha';
}

function mouseUp(e) {
  this.innerHTML="Original Header";
}


//Image Functions:
function onHover()
{
document.querySelector("img[src='https://comic.browserling.com/bytes.png']").setAttribute("src","https://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/themes/codepen/images/codepen-logo-midgray.svg");
console.log("Hovering Left...");
}

function offHover()
{
document.querySelector("img[src='https://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/themes/codepen/images/codepen-logo-midgray.svg']").setAttribute("src","https://comic.browserling.com/bytes.png");
console.log("Out Left...");
}
function onHover2()
{
document.querySelector("img[src='https://www.thecoderpedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Programming-Memes-Programmer-while-sleeping.jpg']").setAttribute("src","https://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/themes/codepen/images/codepen-logo-midgray.svg");  
console.log("Hovering Right...");
}
function offHover2()
{
document.querySelector("img[src='https://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/themes/codepen/images/codepen-logo-midgray.svg']").setAttribute("src","https://www.thecoderpedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Programming-Memes-Programmer-while-sleeping.jpg");  
console.log("Out Right...");
}

//Play with header
document.querySelector("h4").style = "background-color: yellow; text-align:center; border: blue; border-width: medium; border-style: dotted; padding: 25px;";
document.querySelector("h4").addEventListener('mouseover',mouseOver);
document.querySelector("h4").addEventListener('mouseleave',mouseUp);
document.querySelector("h4").addEventListener('mousedown',mouseDown);
document.querySelector("h4").addEventListener('mouseup',mouseUp);

//Play with images
document.querySelector("img[src='https://comic.browserling.com/bytes.png']").addEventListener('mouseover',onHover);
document.querySelector("img[src='https://comic.browserling.com/bytes.png']").addEventListener('mouseleave',offHover);
document.querySelector("img[src='https://www.thecoderpedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Programming-Memes-Programmer-while-sleeping.jpg']").addEventListener('mouseover',onHover2);
document.querySelector("img[src='https://www.thecoderpedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Programming-Memes-Programmer-while-sleeping.jpg']").addEventListener('mouseleave',offHover2);
```